# Not aligned row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know how to make a crooked line.

I uploaded a simple image to make you understand what I want .

http://www.bootply.com/8Lrlo7wASM#

[image: image with horizontally distributed boxes]

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on

```
  .example.big {
        height : 150px;
  }
```

no space between selector.

change it to-

```
  .example .big {
        height : 150px;
  }
```

[link of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juvs1wj3/)